# Equivalent of S27c512-20A PLCC for project

Tags: microcontroller

I've found interesting project for modification of an age old NMT Ericsson 430 Hotline mobile telephone to radio amateur station on 70 cm: https://web.archive.org/web/20040902185654/http://kotisivu.mtv3.fi/oh6mf/modif/ericsson/erics433/e433ohje/e433os1.htm (sorry, page is in Swedish, google translate can not translate link in a moment ). One of the first requirements for modification of telephone is to burn .bin file to  S27c512-20A PLCC  EPROM which is hard to find, is it possible to find equivalent for this EPROM?

Comment: Hi! I know this is an old post, but... I have a couple if S275C12-15A lying around. If you still need them I can send them to you (if -15A are o.k. for your project).

Answer (score 1):

I searched eBay for 27C256 and 27C512 and found loads at low prices. The way I read the article, you only need a 256, the 512 doesn't seem to get you additional benefit.

If you can find a datasheet for the S27c512-20A, you can verify which alternatives have fast enough timing.

It's likely that the '-20A' means 200ns Max access time/min cycle time, so parts with a faster access time (suffix less than 20 should work).

You will of course need a programmer for these parts... do you have access to one? And software to run it?  If not, this thread may be helpful: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/help-in-copying-a-set-of-eprom-%2827c256%29-and-programable-memory-9306/15/

[Edit]

I've recently noted the availability of relatively inexpensive programmers on eBay and Amazon, including ones that can be driven from USB. So that would be a good place to start hunting, if a programmer is needed.